# sum two or more numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

i have a simple code

```
orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
charA = "a"
charB= "b"
charC="c"

for i in charA:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '2')
for i in charB:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '22')
for i in charC:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '222')

print(orgtxt)
```

the above code results will be (222222) if the input was (abc)

now i want to sum each line with a specific number (30) so it will do this

```
orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
charA = "a"
charB= "b"
charC="c"

for i in charA:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '2')
sum = orgtxt + 30

for i in charB:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '22')
sum = orgtxt + 30

for i in charC:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '222')
sum = orgtxt + 30

print(orgtxt)
```

i need it to

- look in the input text for any char (a)
- replace it with (2)
- then, add (30)

and continue to look for any char (b)

- replace it with (22)
- add (30) and so on...

then in the end it will show me the final results which will be (3252252) if the input is (abc)

## ****************************

Ok, here is a clear instructions

prompt user for input

```
orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
```

define strings for inputed user text to be replaced in the next steps

```
charA = "a"
charB= "b"
charC="c"
charD="d"
```

and so on for all chars from A~Z so any text the user will type, it will be replaced with specific number which will be a serial numbers starting from 201 ~ 227

here i search for the code for any letter A and i will replace it with number (201)

```
for i in charA:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '201')
```

then i need to sum result (201)'s with a specific number (30)

```
sum = int(orgtxt) + 30
```

So the results here will be (231)

continue to run the code and search for any letter B and replace it with (202)

```
for i in charB:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '202')
```

then i need to sum result (202)'s with a specific number (30)

```
sum = int(orgtxt) + 30
```

So the results here will be (232)

continue to run the code and search for any letter C and replace it with (203)

```
for i in charC:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '203')
```

then i need to sum result (203)'s with a specific number (30)

```
sum = int(orgtxt) + 30
```

So the results here will be (233)

code will have definitions for all chars A~Z from 201 to 227

sum every replaced char (with the given number) and then

```
print(orgtxt)
```

To print the final results which could be for example (231242239) if user input was (Ali)

231 was originally (A) replaced with number (201) and then sum with (30)

242 was originally (L) replaced with number (212) and then sum with (30)

239 was originally (i) replaced with number (209) and then sum with (30)

Comment: Three important questions (I'm still not sure I understand):
What would be result for `"aabc"` and for `"ababbc"`?

Should `"a"` and `"A"` be treated the same?

What should happen with characters, that are not in the table like `" "` or `"#"` or `"?"` or '0', '1', .... '9'

Comment: You are aware, that `for i in charA:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '201')` does exactly the same as `orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(charA, '201')` ? To iterate through a string with length 1 is not useful.
In any case replace will replace all occurrencies in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should explain once more.

you have the example `"abc"`

after replacing `"a"` with `"2"` you would have

`"2bc"`

What do you mean with adding 30 to `"2bc"`?????

Please explain also what result you'd like to have for the string

`"aabc"` and what for `"ababbc"` ?

I suggest you explain step by step in your question what you'd like to have. Then it will be easy to write a program for it, but without some examples everybody will probably interpret your question differently and all you get will be wild guesses.

In fact writing an unambiguous question is rather difficult, but necessary if you want good answers.

One issue is, that you have to convert a string into a number (an int) before being able to do any arithmetic operation.

if you have the string `"2"` (e.g. `a = "2"`) and you want to perform operations (add for example a `30`), then you have to convert it (e.g.
`rslt = int(a) + 30`)

Also if you have numbers and you want to concatenate them, then you have to convert them to strings first.
so with `a=12` and `b=54`  you had to do `str(a)` + `str(b)` to get `"1254"`.

Her another attempt for an answer, but I have the impression I completely misinterpreted your question

Please give example input and example expected results and explain step by step.
For example do you add 30 only one for all `a`s or do you want to add `30` foe each `a` what do you do with letters that aren't `a`, `b`, or `c`, ...

```
orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
charA = "a"
charB= "b"
charC="c"
num_to_add = 30

result = ""
for i in orgtxt:
    if i == charA:
        result = result + str(num_to_add + 2)
    elif i == charB:
        result = result + str(num_to_add + 22)
    elif i == charC:
        result = result + str(num_to_add + 222)


print(result)
```

if this is what you want, then following should yield an identical result, except, that any letters that are not a,b,c would be conserved with the second code and dropped with the first one:

```
orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(charA, str(num_to_add + 2))
orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(charB, str(num_to_add + 22))
orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(charC, str(num_to_add + 222))

print(orgtxt)
```

Comment: if i use this code
orgtxt = input("Enter text: ")
charA = "a"
charB= "b"
charC="c"

for i in charA:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '2')
for i in charB:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '22')
for i in charC:
    orgtxt = orgtxt.replace(i, '222')

print(orgtxt)

it will keep (orgtxt) in memory to show the final results in the last print method, how do i achieve the same with sum?

Comment: I added my answer. is this what you mean?

Comment: no, in the end, i want it to show me the final results which will be (3252252) if the input is (abc)

Comment: In fact my answer will not work as int(orgtxt) works only if orgtxt at this moment would be a string representing a valid number / integer. This is no the case except the input would only contain "a"s. 
I suggest you explain exactly what you want with at least one example.

You might have to use the int() function to convert a string into a number, but only if it is a valid number string

Comment: Now I have code, that returns the expected result for 'abc', but there is far to much freedom of interpretation in the question. So chances are low, that this is what you need if you don't give further examples and explain a little more.

Comment: How about prompt user for input text (abc), then starting to replace each single char, (a) as (2) then sum 2+30 then store the sum results in a temporary var .. do the same for all chars, and in the end of code it prints the final results from the temporary vars? As of this case (3252252)

Comment: Should i create a temporary var for each char? Or is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what you want (and I guess others don't understand either). Please explain step by step, give two more examples like for `"aabc"` and  `"ababbc"` end explain what to do with characters that are neither a,b or c foe example `"ababXbc"`
The case where each letter occurs only once is a special case.
It's also important to have an example where identical letters are not next to each other. as I said the whole algorithm is still not 100% clear, so difficult to give advice on the best implementation

Comment: you say, that the result should be 30 + 2 * amount of  `a`s concatenated with 30 + 22 * amount of `b`s concatenated with 30 + 222 * amount of `c`s.

As you see with current specifications there is still a lot space of interpretation

Comment: please note as well as something as systematic as `A -> 201`m `B -> 202`, ... `Z ->  226` can be coded without having to code 26 if statements. I can show you how as soon as you clarify the the algorithm. a little more.